# What this Unique ID exactly represents?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

While executing the below mentioned powershell script, I will get the unique ID of the Azure Virtual Machine. I have a doubt with that. Even when I execute this script in the physical machine, I get an ID. I want to know,

what that ID exactly represents?
Is this ID unique for every machine?

Powershell Script:

> $computerSystemProduct = Get-WmiObject -class
>   Win32_ComputerSystemProduct -namespace root\CIMV2
>
> 'BIOS GUID: "{0}"' -f $computerSystemProduct.UUID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID represents the System Information as a GUID.
This GUID is unique - for every machine.

See for reference 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystemproduct

Answer (score 0):

It's unique for every machine, and you can check the details [here](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/53596/uuid):

> (Universally Unique ID) A 128-bit unique number generated by various
>   algorithms to identify hardware or software. Because the number is so
>   large, for all intents and purposes no two UUIDs can be the same. The
>   reason for UUIDs is that they can be combined from disparate sources
>   into one database without fear of duplication.